# How do I do a landing page like this

Tags: javascript, html

I know some things in HTML5 and jQuery, but I don't know where to start so I can create a landing page like this one: http://www.getblogo.com/

Can you give me tips or suggest articles so I can do the same?

PS: I don't want anyone to do a search at Google for me. I just don't know what to search (how this feature is called, to be more specifically).

Comment: Look at what the page does, and use Google to find out how to do the same thing on your own. Nobody will post a "how to do this" guide for you about that exact layout.

Comment: "*I don't want anyone to do a search at Google for me*" "*I just don't know what to search*". Well maybe if someone *did* show you what to Google you wouldn't have to ask next time, because you'd now? Why so resisting against getting the terms right?

Comment: Its just HTMl & Javascript (jQuery+plugins). You can view the source and learn from it

Comment: Question has already been answered the way I needed. Thank.

Comment: http://bit.ly/15KPcbC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the search term you are looking for is "parallax scrolling" , or "parallax scrolling with animation".

You can find some tutorials here: http://inspiretrends.com/parallax-scrolling-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a website you need to know some basic things:

1. CSS
2. HTML
3. Javascript
4. Some server side language like PHP
5. a Content management system like wordpress (not a must but most sites use it)

these are the basics you must have.

Answer (score 0):

The site was made with [Adobe Muse](http://www.adobe.com/pt/products/muse.html) without writing code

[A Quick Demo of Parallax Scrolling in Adobe Muse CC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvCYqAHy2kU)

Comment: You could download a 30 day trial of this software https://creative.adobe.com/products/muse